Spherical symmetry of Schwarzschild solution
I was reading Regge-Wheeler's 1957 paper titled "Stability of the Schwarzschild Singularity", where in the section II, under the heading "Spherical Symmetry; Specialization to $M = 0$", they argue that due to the spherical symmetry of the background (Schwarzschild) metric, terms of different $L$ and parity do not mix. Also, Birkhoff's theorem states about the uniqueness of the Schwarzschild solution as the only one which is spherically symmetric and asymptotically flat.
In my knowledge, a spherically symmetric function is independent of the angular coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$. But the Schwarzschild metric depends on the coordinate $\theta$. How could it be possibly spherically symmetric?

Where exactly did you get the idea that "the Schwarzschild metric depends on the coordinate θ"? Because it does not.

@VincentThacker I think you should not be so prickly with so many posts. I think the OP is just meaning that there is the $(r,\mathrm d\vartheta)^2+(r\sin\vartheta,\mathrm d\varphi)^2$, with the offending $\sin\vartheta$ part triggering the confusion. To us in the know, of course we know that this isn't what we mean by "depends", but it is a legitimate possible confusion for OP to drop into.

It hasthe component $g_{\phi\phi}=r^2\sin^{2}{\theta}$, so isn't it depending on $\theta$ ?

@AnantBadal Hint: A tensor comprises components and basis.

@naturallyInconsistent And I think you should be less aggressive in your tone. I was simply asking the OP what they meant by "the metric depending on $\theta$". In physics and even more so in mathematics, terminology has precise meaning. The metric does not have the same meaning as the metric components. But it's too bad that both things are often referred to as the "metric", causing confusion.

@naturallyInconsistent And the fact that even you yourself had to guess: "I think the OP is just meaning..." shows that it could be made clearer.

" In euclidean space this distance is equal to the radius vector; in a non-euclidean space, such as we have in the presence of a gravitational field, there is no quantity which has all the properties of the euclidean radius vector (for example to be equal both to the distance from the center and to the length of the circumference divided by $2\pi $). Therefore the choice of a “radius vector” is now arbitrary." Landau, Lifchitz .

See also https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-1100-6

https://archive.org/details/landau-l.-d.-lifshitz-e.-m.-course-of-theoretical-vol-2/page/298/mode/1up?view=theater

The accepted answer is fine, but is an overkill. Just take the metric of an ordinary sphere and you would see the same $\phi$ and $\theta$ there despite the obvious spherical symmetry.

Starting from the transformation of Cartesian coordinates $x,y,z$ into spherical coordinates:
$x = r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$;
$y = r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$;
$z = r\cos(\theta)$
The differential $dx$ is:
$$dx = \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}dr + \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}d\theta +\frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}d\phi$$
After getting $dy$ and $dz$ in a similar way, the arc parameter $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$ can be shown to be: $ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2d\theta^2 + r^2\sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2$
Now, suppose that the Cartesian axis are rotated, keeping the same origin. A point $P(x,y,z)$ is now represented as $P(x',y',z')$, and a new spherical coordinates keeping the same $r$, but with $\theta'$ and $\phi'$ are defined.
The arc parameter $ds$ is defined for the new coordinates as $ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2d\theta'^2 + r^2\sin^2(\theta')d\phi'^2$
Only the names of the angular coordinates are changed, but the form of the metric is the same.
Now, going to Schwarzschild metric, the functions of $r$ are not modified because this variable doesn't change by an axis rotation. So, its form is also preserved.
